# C# JSON Deserialization: How to get values out of a JSON array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I am trying to create an array from a .json array and get only 2 variables in the array (keyName and token) out of the whole current .json array.

The .json that is being received by an api call:

```
{
  "project": [
   {
      "id": 1,
      "keyName": "John123",
      "age": "19",
      "token": "123456789"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "keyName": "Mary123",
      "age": "13",
      "token": "23435"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "keyName": "Harry123",
      "age": "23",
      "token": "2343542"
    }
  ] 
}
```

I only want an array that has the keyName and token being shown for each object, how can I do this?

At the moment I have used an api call to get the .json file then I have parsed it into an array as shown below:

```
 Projects = JArray.Parse(resp.Content);
```

Please help as I am new to C#, sorry if some doesn't make sense my english isnt very good.

Comment: What you show is NOT valid JSON. Please show what you actually receive, without mangling it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
  "project": [
   {
      "id": 1,
      "keyName": "John123",
      "age": "19",
      "token": "123456789"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "keyName": "Mary123",
      "age": "13",
      "token": "23435"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "keyName": "Harry123",
      "age": "23",
      "token": "2343542"
    }
  ] 
}
```

You can use **`Newtonsoft.Json`** framework for json manipulation, which you can install from **`NuGet Package Manager`**. Then do a **`Project`** model with the data that you need. You can abstract it even further with **`JSONData`** class, so if your json data grows you can just add new properties to it. After that just deserialize it.

```
public class Project
{
    public string KeyName { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
}

public class JSONData
{
    public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class Deserializer
{
    //---------------- FIELDS -----------------
    private readonly string path = @"../../yourJsonFile.json";
    private readonly JSONData jsonData;
    
    //------------- CONSTRUCTORS --------------
    public Deserializer() {
        this.jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONData>(File.ReadAllText(this.path));
    }
}
```

That way you won't duplicate deserialization code like this

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Project>>(path);
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Category>>(path);
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize JSON file with help of [JsonSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer?view=net-5.0#methods).

First thing you need to do is create C# class that will describe json data. It can be regular POCO class. In your case it will look similar to this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string KeyName {get; set;}
    public string Token {get; set;}
}
```

Then all you need to do is get data from API via [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0) and call `.Deserialize` method of JsonSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting with the format of the json document, to be able to deserialize the object.

Valid json format:

```
{
  "project": [
   {
      "id": 1,
      "keyName": "John123",
      "age": "19",
      "token": "123456789"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "keyName": "Mary123",
      "age": "13",
      "token": "23435"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "keyName": "Harry123",
      "age": "23",
      "token": "2343542"
    }
  ] 
}
```

You should then create a Key object:

```
public class Project
{       
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string keyname { get; set; }
    public string age {get;set;}
    public string token {get;set;}
}
```

You can now serialize the json as an array of the key object, and query it via Linq

```
    List<Project> projects = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Project>>("content of the json file");
    var keyAndToken = projects.Select(c=> c.keyname, c.token);
```